# How can I get access to the InOut behaviour in a Custom Camel Component (Apollo)

Tags: apache-camel, apollo

I am busy developing a Camel Component for Apollo using the HawtDispatch Apollo Client library for Scala.
I am successful with sending and receiving of messages from queues and topics but I do not know how I can determine that the current producer (StompProducer) requires inOut or InOnly behaviour. For InOut I want to subscribe to a temporary queue to get the result if no explicit replyTo is provided. 
Am I barking up the wrong tree? Are there any examples I can look at? Has somebody already done an Apollo Stomp Component?
I have tried using the ActiveMQ component to bind to the OpenWire protocol in Apollo 1.5  but that did not work well. The Sjms Camel component in Camel 2.11-SNAPSHOT also did not work for me.
The end goal is to have Apollo Consumer/Producers Actors for Akka.
Any advice on alternatives for Camel Apollo integration or on getting my own attempt at a Component working, will be much appreciated. 
Regards
Ian

Comment: You get this done?  You opensourcing it?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer: when processing an exchange you can test if is an inOut exchange by using exchange.getPattern.isOutCapable.